# JQuery "Cloning" on a "Click" event is not triggered for all buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Jquery "Cloning" on a "Click" event is not triggered for all buttons, its only working in first button. I need to make it triggered for all buttons. Can someone help me to solve it?

Here is the code below:

```js
//$(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();

$('.LPclone').click(function() {
  $('.widgetWrap').clone().appendTo('#tempEditorView');
});
```

```css
.widgetWrap {
  padding: 30px 10px;
  align-self: baseline;
}

.widgetHeading {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #222;
  position: relative;
}

.LPclone {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tempEditorView">
  <div class="widgetHeading widgetWrap" style="display: block;">
    <div class="LPtempEditArea"><i class="LPclone">Clone</i></div>
    <h1 contenteditable="true">Add your heading text here</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Issact/sL4q3ohh/2/

Comment: Since the cloned ones are dynamincally added in the DOM, you need to use `on()` and not just `click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click` will not bind the click event to the dynamically generated elements. You need to delegate the event

```
$("#tempEditorView").on('click', '.LPclone', function(){
        $('.widgetWrap').clone().appendTo('#tempEditorView');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
$(document).on('click','.LPclone',function(event){
    $('.widgetWrap').clone().appendTo('#tempEditorView');
         });
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/sL4q3ohh/6/)

Comment: Thank you vel, You are right! but i don't need a "first-child" for my condition..

Answer (score 0):

```
.click not bind with dynamic generated class

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.LPclone').on('click',function() {
        $('.widgetWrap').clone().appendTo('#tempEditorView');
      });

    })

or

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.LPclone').live('click',function() {
    $('.widgetWrap').clone().appendTo('#tempEditorView');
  });

})
both are working but ".live" is not working for updated jquery.
```